# why don't I need to include cctype while using ispunct?

Tags: c++

I'm reading *C++ Primer 5th* and from page 83 I have put this code in VS.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string s("Hello World!!!");
    decltype(s.size()) punct_cnt = 0;
    for (auto c : s) {
        if (ispunct(c)) {
            ++punct_cnt;
        }
    }

    cout << punct_cnt << " punctuation characters in " << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was taught that **ispunct**, **isalpha** are defined in **cctype**, how can I use these functions directly without include header files? I tried to compile this file in cmd, all worked.

Comment: probably because they are included by the iostream or string header you included

Comment: You do need to include it, if you want your code to be portable. Just because one compiler happens to include it in another file doesn't mean all of them will. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421334/does-the-standard-specify-what-headers-include-other-headers

Comment: it works on GCC but it doesn't work on Clang. Try running an example given here by removing header files and keep changing the compiler to different versions. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that both `<iostream>` and `<string>` headers do not include `<cctype>` directly. However, in the case of `<iostream>`, if you delve into the rabbit hole, you can find `<bits/localefwd.h>` and `<bits/locale_facets.h>` headers, which include `<cctype>` in their source code.

The long answer, however, is quite cumbersome, but it is a good practice to see how `<cctype>` is scattered across the code base. In the case of `<iostream>`, the header includes `<istream>`, which, in turn, includes the `<ios>` header. From there, you should chase each header. My personal result is represented below. Keep in mind that it may differ in your case. (The `+>` notation here means "includes")

```
ios +> bits/localefwd.h +> cctype


ios +> bits/ios_base.h +> bits/localefwd.h +> cctype
ios +> bits/ios_base.h +> bits/locale_classes.h +> bits/localefwd.h +> cctype


ios +> streambuf +> bits/localefwd.h +> cctype
ios +> streambuf +> bits/ios_base.h +> bits/localefwd.h +> cctype
ios +> streambuf +> bits/ios_base.h +> bits/locale_classes.h +> bits/localefwd.h +> cctype


ios +> basic_ios.h +> bits/localefwd.h +> cctype

ios +> basic_ios.h +> bits/locale_classes.h +> bits/localefwd.h +> cctype

ios +> basic_ios.h +> bits/locale_facets.h +> cctype

ios +> basic_ios.h +> bits/streambuf_iterator.h +> streambuf +> bits/localefwd.h +> cctype
ios +> basic_ios.h +> bits/streambuf_iterator.h +> streambuf +> bits/ios_base.h +> bits/localefwd.h +> cctype
ios +> basic_ios.h +> bits/streambuf_iterator.h +> streambuf +> bits/ios_base.h +> bits/locale_classes.h +> bits/localefwd.h +> cctype
```

Note that `<locale_facets>` includes `<cctype>`, even though it could have worked without it (since it includes `<streambuf>`). *That is the practice you should acquire in your code too; otherwise, you will harm portability and add to your technical debt.*

Comment: Yes even if a header is indirectly included I would always include the headers in which the used types/functions are defined directly, especially because what headers a indirectly included can vary between the differnt std implemenations and versions. A tool like [Include What You Use](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use) can help with that task.